# how can I restore site on different farm?

Tags: backup, restore

I have a PRE site that has all functionality inside (front, sql server, etc) and a PRO farm with four servers (farm- front- sql server- search-owa) and I want to have a working copy on PRE, so in case of error in PRO I can use the PRE site while I repair PRO.
I should use Site backup or there is something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

First make sure both PRO and PRE are having the same SharePoint versions.

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.BuildVersion
```

Then you can do a Sitecollection backup and restore using PowerShell

```
Backup-SPSite http://sharepoint.com/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak

Restore-SPSite http://sharepoint.com/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

If you only want to restore a site(web) then you can save the site as a template and restore it back in PRE.

Recommend way is site collection backup restore.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is after making sure both farm are same build level, customization level (features, authentication etc).

Then you can take the backup of content database from pro farm and restore that database on pre farm,s Sql server. After this you have to attached content db to the pre farm.